# What ciphers do I have available in MySQL Client?

Tags: mysql, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, percona

I am having the cryptic error when trying to connect to a remote MySQL 5.6 (Percona node) server with `mysql` and **Workbench** using SSL. I have made my own signed certificates and my own CA.

`mysql -h host -p -u user --ssl-ca=ca-cert.pem`

> ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: protocol version mismatch

I have read around that I should include the cipher option. So I SSH into the server and rerun the same command (without the host) to pluck the cipher for the local connection.

```
mysql>  show session status like '%cipher';
+---------------+-----------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                       |
+---------------+-----------------------------+
| Ssl_cipher    | ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 |
+---------------+-----------------------------+
```

When I retry including the cipher I get the next error message.

`mysql -h host -p -u user --ssl-ca=ca-cert.pem --ssl-cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256`

> ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: Failed to set ciphers to use

I understand from [Connect to MySQL using SHA2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43402892/2733184) that my client is most likely incapable of using SHA256 or higher to connect.

I checked the available server ciphers that do not have high SHA:

```
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA
DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
AES128-SHA
DH-DSS-AES128-SHA
ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
AES256-SHA
DH-DSS-AES256-SHA
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA
```

I've tried these ciphers to no avail. Can anyone help me diagnose the issue? Could it be a problem with my certificates? or are the certificates determining the cipher?

### Update: linked libraries

I have checked my server, `mysqld`'s SSL is linked against

```
libssl.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
```

Nevertheless, I know for a fact that the Percona version is linked against OpenSSL.
The client is compiled against

````
linux-vdso.so.1 => 
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
libz.so.1       => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
libdl.so.2      => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
libtinfo.so.5   => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5
libstdc++.so.6  => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
libm.so.6       => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
libgcc_s.so.1   => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
libc.so.6       => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2```
````

I don't see anything SSL related there but `libdl` is present which means that there might be dynamic loading. However, I suspect that this client may well be compiled for YaSSL.

Answer (score 1):

Read the manual page https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encrypted-connection-protocols-ciphers.html

It lists the ciphers that MySQL passes to OpenSSL and yaSSL. Your client may be compiled with one or the other of OpenSSL or yaSSL.

Comment: I guess you should have started by helping me find out what my client is compiled with. I don't actually know, but I think I can find out somehow. BTW, you're sending me a link to the 5.7 ref when I explicitly described the server as a _MySQL 5.6 (Percona node) server_. I'll go check out https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encrypted-connection-protocols-ciphers.html and look for a solution there

Comment: My client is most surely compiled against YaSSL. I have checked with all ciphers present in both sets and now the error switched back to `protocol version mismatch`. Is there any way to hookup my client to the server? Is this an insurmountable incompatibility? Does this merit a new question in SO?